# Dynamically changing text messages via Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, animation

I have a slight problem that I don't know how to solve. So basically I have a MySQL database, which contains various text strings (lets call them tips). There is just one column called "messages" and in each row there is one tip.
The aim is to display these tips on a webpage. But, I want the tips to change dynamically automatically. In other words, I want lets say every 10 seconds to change the tip. Also, I wanted the tip to be chosen randomly.
My plan was to make a div, where every specified interval, the page will make an Ajax call, where a random number will be generated and used as the row number in the MySQL to display the tip in the div.

In fact I was actually able to do all this. But the last thing I would like is for the text to actually change using some form of a transition, such as fading effect etc. Right now, the content just simply switches from one text to another. I guess the best way would be using jQuery, but I just dont know how to implement it.... Here is my current code, right now the text changes upon clicking on a button, but I would add the automatic switch later, thats not a problem. Also, the text from ajax right now is just static, not fetched from the MySQL, this is just for testing purposes and I know how to do that quite easily.

Here is the code of the page with the text:

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"></script>
<script>
function text(){

var xmlhttp;    
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
     document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","message_ajax.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" onclick="text()" value="Show" class="button">
<div id="message">X</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the actual Ajax page:

```
<?php
    echo "Y";
?>
```

So in this testing script, when I click the button, the page makes an ajax call and the "X" in the div switches to "Y", but is it someshow possible to switch the text using some animation?

Comment: Is it really worth fetching each of these text strings individually?  How big is this table?  If there are only a few dozen it might make more sense to include them all in the markup and only switch which one is visible every 10 seconds (this would also make transitions easier).  If there are a large number in the DB, at least fetch 10-20 each time instead of 1.  Otherwise you are making a ton of unnecessary requests to the server for every single visitor.

Comment: Well the table is actually quite large and Im adding rows quite often, plus I want to use it on several pages so that would require always copying the new strings to every single page.

Comment: True - although there are still other ways to do this (i.e. a php function that fetches 20 rows on page load, then using ajax to get 20 more once it becomes needed) that will not bog your server down as much as individual requests for each row.  I really don't think you want a request to the server every 10 seconds per visitor per page.  If you get any kind of real traffic that will become a performance issue very quickly.

Comment: of course, sorry that was just a random time interval that I wrote, because thats irrelevant in terms of the actual coding. It would be longer of course. Still though, would you know how to do the transition effect?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AJAX functionality and want to do animations, jQuery is a must-have. If you are just doing AJAX, you can get away without jQuery, but as soon as you have the need to use the functionality that jQuery provides in several places around a page it becomes worth the slight overhead.

That said, you will want to do something like this:

```
$('#message').fadeOut(function()
{
    $(this).html(msg).fadeIn();
});
```

Javascript gets executed by the browser on the current page. This code should go inside `<script>` tags at the bottom of the page.

Technically, you can just put it in the `script` tags that are already at the top of your page, but there are supposed performance increases in keeping your JS at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I know, so where should I then place the code you posted? In the actual page? In the Ajax page?